# Dependency Injection framework for C++

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

Is there a DI framework comparable to Google Guice? And what does Google use?

Comment: This is similar to guice: https://bitbucket.org/cheez/dicpp

Comment: Since the May of 2014 the Google has been creating [the fruit](https://github.com/google/fruit) - dependency injection framework for C++, loosely inspired by the Guice.

Comment: If you are looking for C++11 lib you can take a look at cppdi: http://code.google.com/p/cppdi (I'm author)

Comment: https://github.com/boost-ext/di

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is nothing as mature or standard as Guice in the C++ world. However, some people have put together simplistic implementations on their own. Here's a couple.

- http://adam.younglogic.com/2008/07/dependency-injection-in-c/ (source for implementation is at the end of the post)
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtioccontainer/ (requires Qt)
- http://code.google.com/p/autumnframework/ (hasn't been touched since 2007)
- http://programmaticallyspeaking.blogspot.com/2010/04/beautiful-dependency-injection-in-c.html (more of a description, really)
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-resolver/ ("Alpha" quality)

You're unlikely to be satisfied by any of these.

If you really wanted to put in the effort to rally the world around a DI framework for C++, probably the way to go about it would be to make a proposal to the Boost guys.

Comment: I fear to think about the template-meta-programming combined with a pinch of macros which will be involved in the Boost's version of GUICE... ;-)

Comment: Lol :) I think the same. Boost is really to heavy. Just look at its signal/slot library. It has zillion features that probably no one will use that add overhead and complexity :/. Boost is not a trivial dependency for any project and increase compile time a lot and so quick iteration is harder

Answer (score 28):

I'm the author of [wallaroo](http://wallaroolib.sourceforge.net/). It's actively developed and has the following features:

- it's lightweight but powerful
- its interface supports both C++11 and C++98 with boost
- it's type safe
- it doesn't need custom preprocessors / code generators
- you can load classes defined in shared libraries
- you can use a DSL syntax for object creation and wiring or
- you can get object creation and wiring by parsing one or more xml / json file.

Any comment, suggestion or request are welcome.

Comment: Looks good; as for the XML storing configuration do you think you could also add examples—and support—JSON?

Comment: @AT Thanks: I'm trying to keep wallaroo quality high. In january a new release will be available, with new features, JSON support and more examples.

Comment: ... sadly it is an intrusive container. You have to derive your classes from wallaroo::Device. This is a K.O. criteria from my point of view, should be non-intrusive.

Comment: @Beachwalker yes, you need to derive your classes from wallaroo::Device. Sadly, a non-intrusive container mean you need to run a custom preprocessor / code generator.

Comment: @Daniele What about just writing proxies/wrapper to make classes configurable and return the the internal object after creation/method call? Haven't seen yet in the c++ world but is used in spring for example. I know they use reflection, but I would prefer to write a "handmade" proxy to make a class configurable instead of changing the code provided by 3rd party.

Comment: @Beachwalker If you only need the "creation" feature you can actually solve the problem by writing a wrapper of 3rd party classes (the usual indirection layer that solve every CS problem :-) . However, in this way you cannot exploit the "wiring" feature of wallaroo. BTW: maybe I'll add a non-intrusive creation mechanism to wallaroo.

Comment: @Daniele Adding an option to use a non-intrusive mechanism would be cool. Looking forward to see that.

Answer (score 25):

There is a recent one that looks very interesting called [Hypodermic](https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic/wiki/Registering-concrete-types), i haven't tested it but it looks pretty active

Comment: Cool thing, but has no ability to load config from files (as Spring does). So you're forced to have some sources and a compiler right next to the app you want to re-configure. That is a problem of those "fluent" IoC's. Would prefer something where it is possible to mix "hard coded" configs with "flexible file" configs, e.g. XML.

Comment: @Beachwalker: it is a possible feature to add. I Actually prefer to load a configuration from an xml file then hard code my components layout from that loaded configuration.

Comment: @misterwhy What do you put into the xml file (classes and their dependencies)? Is there a sample demonstration how to do that?

Comment: @Beachwalker, I imagine misterwhy meant that he makes his own "feature-based" config file format, and then sets up the container himself using hardcoded combinations of objects based on specific features. And I kind of agree. That way you don't have (as much, at least) untyped dependency information in "random" text files.

Answer (score 11):

I am currently authoring one called [sauce](https://github.com/phs/sauce), whose design (and name) is directly inspired by guice.  I still consider it alpha, but you may find it useful.

Comment: +1 I will keep an eye on it :-).

Comment: Implementation is missing a file based configuration method (e.g. XML). Would prefer that instead of "fluent-only" configs (because needs a compiler even for quick config changes). Anyway +1 for sharing this link, didn't knew this IoC before.

Comment: It's my opinion that XML is the devil.

Comment: @phs Why? Ok, if XML is the devil... how would you suggest to change the configuration without compilation of source files using sauce? I'm not saying sauce is bad, I'm just saying it's (imho) missing an important thing, especially essential for huge applications with heavy integration support requirements, e.g. for heterogenous legacy hardware and per seat optimization. I think, a DI framework should allow BOTH ways (code and file) and should be easy to interchange with each way.

Comment: @Beachwalker It's understandable, but I believe parsing config files is outside of the DI tool's responsibility.  Instead, the tool should make it easy to select desired bindings at runtime.  Sauce does this in two ways.  One, by allowing control flow around module inclusion (you could imagine an `if` around either of [these](https://github.com/phs/sauce/blob/ac11912/test/tutorial_test.cc#L516-517)) and by [module instances](https://github.com/phs/sauce/blob/ac11912/sauce/modules.h#L135), which can be constructed after parsing any config files that the application author desires.