# Injecting an implementation into a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Consider the following example:

```
class A{
public: virtual void  hello() = 0;
};

class B: public A{};

class C {
    public: void hello(){
        cout<<"Hi";
    }
};
class D: public B, public C{};
```

The idea is that I would like to inject the implementation of `hello`  into `D` through `C`. This doesn't seem to work unless I make `C` inherit from A too. Since that leads to diamond inheritance, I end up using virtual inheritance.

Is there any alternative to forcing an implementation into a derived class, without disturbing the abstract classes `A` and `B` here?

EDIT: I want a solution where I don't need to explicitly write code within `D`. This is because, I have many classes like `D` having the same implementation, which is exactly why I would like to push that implementation up to some class from which all of them inherit.

Comment: which version do u want in `D`? `B::hello()` or `C::hello()` ?

Comment: if u want `B::hello()` in `D` you can simply use `using B::hello()` in `D`

Comment: I want to implement `A::hello()` in `D`. For which I want to use `C`'s implementation.

Comment: u mean to implement `A::hello()` in `D` and call `C::hello()` in the implementation?

Comment: Yes. But without *actually* writing any code in D explicitly. Just by using inheritance.  For example, I solved it with virtual inheritance. I want to know if there's any other method.

Comment: u have to atleast implement `hello()` in `D` since this is pure virtual in `A`

Comment: can u implement `A::hello()` in `B`?

Comment: There are some DI frameworks for this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469304/dependency-injection-framework-for-c

Comment: Why not derive `class C` from `class B`, and `class D` only inherits `class C`?

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite C as a template class that inherits from it's template argument and then derive D from C.

```
template <class Base>
class C : public Base {
    public: void hello(){
        cout<<"Hi";
    }
};
class D: public C<B> {};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider static inheritance/ policy classes when you need to *inject* an outside method into a class hierarchy. Note that injecting the method usually means that the method does not have the same name as an existing virtual in the class hierarchy (if it does, you are forced to use virtual inheritance or explicitly call with the scope `::` or insert it in the class hierarchy). I called the method `externalHello` here.

The other options work fine as well but they conceptually point more to the fact that the injected method is not really an abstract method that could be used outside of this class hierarchy but should have been part of it in the first place.

```
class A
{
    public: 
        virtual void  hello() = 0;
};

class B: public A 
{
    public: 
    void hello()
    {
        cout<<"Hi from B" << endl;
    };

};

template<typename T> class C1 
{
    public: 
    void injectedMethodUnrelatedToClassHierarchy()
    {
        cout<<"Hi from C1 with unrelated method" << endl;
    };    
    void externalHello() 
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->hello(); // will still call hello in B
        injectedMethodUnrelatedToClassHierarchy(); // this will call hello here
    };
};

class D: public B, public C1<D>{};
```

With client code:

```
D dx;    
dx.hello();
dx.externalHello();
dx.injectedMethodUnrelatedToClassHierarchy();
```

Comment: So it is not possible for the injected method to be able to override some method in the class hierarchy?

Comment: then you would have to insert the class into the class hierarchy (and choose where you want to do that, using a template makes it easier to select the location as suggested by D Drmmr) rather than make the classes that should have that function available derive from the function container (across different class hierarchies). Depends on what you conceptually prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It may work

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
 public: 
    virtual void  hello() = 0;
};

class C {
   public: void hello(){
    cout<<"Hi\n";
  }
};

template<typename T>
class B: public A, public T
{
  public:   
    void hello() override{ //override A::hello()
    //do other staff

    T::hello(); // call C::hello()
   }
};



 class D: public B<C>{

  };

 int main()
 {
  D d;
  d.hello();
  return 0;
 }
```