# Should abstract members of a class be pointers or references?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, abstract-class, class-members

Should abstract members of a class be pointers or references?

For a toy example, say I have the following class:

```
class SerializedFileProcessor {
public:
    std::string Process(std::string file) const {
        std::string text = deserializer.Deserialize(file);
        text = processor.Process(text);
        return serializer.Serialize(text);
    }

private:
    IDeserializer? deserializer;
    IProcessor? processor;
    ISerializer? serializer; 
};
```

Where the (instances of concrete subclasses) deserializer, processor, and serializer are all passed into this class's constructor.

The SerializedFileProcessor doesn't own these and should not delete them.

Should those class members be pointers or references? Or should this pattern be done completely differently?

Comment: I don't see this having anything to do with abstract-ness.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but since the type IWhatever is abstract, the data cannot be copied into SerializedFileProcessor. That's the only reason I specified they were abstract classes.

Comment: If you are able to use references, always prefer them over pointers.

Comment: It depends on what is constant about them after construction of `SerializedFileProcessor`.  If the type and location can't change then reference is likely OK and if reference is OK then it is likely better.  If the type of the object might change, then its address would need to change and it can't be a reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the hello-world example of dependency injection (/inversion).

There's a similar question here, with different solutions:[Dependency injection in C++11 without raw pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477589/dependency-injection-in-c11-without-raw-pointers)

**Edit**: I moved my original answer from here into to that question.

---

Original answer with `SerializedFileProcessor` example:

The down side of just using a pointer (smart or raw), or even an ordinary C++ reference, is that they allow calling non-const methods from a const context.

I propose a wrapper similar but not identical to `std::reference_wrapper` (which lacks the const safe accessor). Replace `T*` with `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to get owning versions (also add default move construction).

```
  template<typename T>
  struct NonOwningRef{
    NonOwningRef() = delete;
    NonOwningRef(T& other) noexcept : ptr(std::addressof(other)) { };
    NonOwningRef(const NonOwningRef& other) noexcept = default;

    const T& value() const noexcept{ return *ptr; };
    T& value() noexcept{ return *ptr; };

  private:
    T* ptr;
  };
```

usage:

```
class SerializedFileProcessor {
public:
    std::string Process(std::string file) const {
        std::string text = deserializer.value().Deserialize(file);
        text = processor.value().Process(text);
        return serializer.value().Serialize(text);
    }

private:
    NonOwningRef<IDeserializer> deserializer;
    NonOwningRef<IProcessor> processor;
    NonOwningRef<ISerializer> serializer; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a really useful link. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to gear my question more towards DI.

Answer (score 0):

They can be either, you must only ensure that the referenced objects do not die before used (i.e. in general its lifetime should exceed the SerializedFileProcessor lifetime).

There is one disadvantage to reference members - it is then virtually impossible to create an assignment operator (so if you need one, then you need a pointer - there are techniques to actually have assignment even for classes with reference members, but they are very nasty). Also in case they are optional, then they need to be pointers (reference is not optional).

Answer (score -3):

If your class doesn't own them, it should not be a reference. Use a pointer and have the owner hold a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: "If your class doesn't own them, it should not be a reference." This is unclear/wrong. References do not own in C++.

Comment: Actually it is opposite, if it owns it has to be a pointer (raw or smart)